# Passing event argument from child to parent after calling onchange handler from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a markdown previewer where the user enters markdown and sees it rendered in another div. Originally, I had one React component and everything worked fine. Then I wanted to refactor my code so it had one parent component with two child components - one for input and the other for output. Here's my code:

```
var MarkdownPreviewer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      input: ''
    }
  },
  handleInput: function(event){
    this.setState({input: event.target.value});
  },
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Input setInputState = {this.handleInput}/>
        <Output userInput={this.state.input}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Input = React.createClass({
  callHandleInput: function(event){
    this.props.setInputState(event)
  },
  render: function(){
    <div className="input-container">
      <textarea onChange={this.callHandleInput} className="form-control" placeholder="Please enter you Github flavoured markdown"></textarea>
    </div>
  }
});

var Output = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    <div className="output-container" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: marked(this.props.userInput)}}>
    </div>
  }
})

React.render(<MarkdownPreviewer />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

My question is how can I pass the event object from the child component to the parent component so that I can set the state of input in the parent component?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the return statements in your input and output components.

Comment: I've got it on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/edward-hong/pen/ONjXxr?editors=0010) and the component still isn't rendering for some reason

Comment: I'm not sure why but I'd guess it is related to the dangerouslySetInnerHTML in your component. Codepen may not allow it for security reasons, but it's just a guess.

Comment: Btw you are missing return statements in your input and output render functions.

Comment: You sample works perfectly fine on my local computer when you add the return statements :)